# Only allow floating points regex

Tags: grep, regular-expression, numeric-data, floating-point

How can I check if a specific string is a floating points?
This are possible floating points:

```
12.245
+.0009
3.11e33
43.1E11
2e-14
```

This is what I tried:

```
grep "^[+\-\.0-9]" 
grep "^[+-]*[0-9]"
grep "^[+\-\.0-9]"
```

And other lots of related things, but none filtered anything at all. Almost every string got through. How would I tackle this problem?

Comment: Using word boundary for example: `grep -E '(\b\.\b|\b-\b)' yourfile`. Or after reading carefully a simple `grep '[.-]' filename` works

Comment: @val0x00ff strings like 255.255 and 56-89-52 get through, and ain't floating points

Comment: @O'Niel, `255.255` is a valid float number, why did you write *and ain't floating points* ?

Comment: This question was really confusing `This are possible floating points:`. What is `possible`? 2e-15 is not float at all. `+.0009` neither so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grep -xE '[-+]?[0123456789]*\.?[0123456789]+([eE][-+]?[0123456789]+)?'
```

With `-x`, we're anchoring the regexp at the start and and of the line so the lines have to match that pattern as a whole as opposed to the pattern being found anywhere in the line.

If you wanted to match on all the ones supported by [POSIX/C `strtod()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/functions/strtod.html) as recognised by many implementations of the `printf` utility for instance:

```
r=[$(locale decimal_point)]
d=[0123456789]
h=[0123456789abcdefABCDEF]
grep -xE "[[:space:]]*[-+]?($d*$r?$d+([eE][-+]?$d+)?|\
0[xX]$h*$r?$h*([pP][-+]?$d+)?|\
[iI][nN][fF]([iI][nN][iI][tT][yY])?|\
[nN][aA][nN]|\
NAN\([abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_]+\))"
```

So also including things like 0x3f, 0xFP-4, -Infinity, NAN(whatever).

```
$ printf '%g\n' 0x3f 0xFp-4 -Infinity 'NAN(whatever)'
63
0.9375
-inf
nan
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative ***Python*** solution (for *less* sophisticated input items):

Sample `input.txt` file:

```
11
12.245
+.0009
---0
3.11e33
43.1E11
2e-14
t12
aaa
10.001
```

---

**`check_float.py`** script:

```
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as inp:
    f = 'No'
    for l in inp.read().splitlines():
        try:
            if float(l) and '.' in l: f = 'Yes'
        except ValueError:
            f = 'No'
        finally:
            print '{0} - {1}'.format(l, f)
```

---

Usage:

```
python check_float.py input.txt
```

The output:

```
11 - No
12.245 - Yes
+.0009 - Yes
---0 - No
3.11e33 - Yes
43.1E11 - Yes
2e-14 - Yes
t12 - No
aaa - No
10.001 - Yes
```

Comment: It seems to me that as written it should return "No" for 2e-14 as it contains no ".".

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer:  This is an imperfect solution. Perl's `Scalar::Util::looks_like_number()` function may not be the best choice of routine for doing this. See [StéphaneChazelas comments below](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397784/only-allow-floating-points-regex/397795#comment710214_397795).

I'm leaving it here if anyone wants to look at it and pick the `coproc` bits out of it.

---

Rather than trying to craft your own regular expression to match the many possible floating point number format, use a library that already has implemented it:

```bash
perl -MScalar::Util -ne 'exit !Scalar::Util::looks_like_number($_)'
```

As a `bash` shell function:

```bash
is_number () {
    perl -MScalar::Util -ne 'exit !Scalar::Util::looks_like_number($_)' <<<"$1"
}

is_number hello && echo 'hello is a number'
is_number 1.234 && echo '1.234 is a number'
```

As a `bash` co-process (to avoid starting up a Perl process for every time you want to test a number):

```bash
coproc PERLIO=:raw perl -MScalar::Util -ne \
    'print Scalar::Util::looks_like_number($_) ? "Yes" : "No", "\n"'

while IFS= read -r -p 'Number please: ' possnum; do
    printf '%s\n' "$possnum" >&${COPROC[1]}
    read -u ${COPROC[0]}

    case "$REPLY" in
        Yes)    printf '%s is a number\n' "$possnum"       ;;
        No)     printf '%s is _not_ a number\n' "$possnum" ;;
    esac
done

kill "$COPROC_PID"
```

Or combining the two:

```bash
coproc PERLIO=:raw perl -MScalar::Util -ne \
    'print Scalar::Util::looks_like_number($_) ? "Yes" : "No", "\n"'

is_number () {
    printf '%s\n' "$1" >&${COPROC[1]}

    local REPLY
    read -u ${COPROC[0]}

    [ "$REPLY" = 'Yes' ] && return 0

    return 1
}

while IFS= read -r -p 'Number please: ' possnum; do
    if is_number "$possnum"; then
        printf '%s is a number\n' "$possnum"
    else
        printf '%s is a _not_ a number\n' "$possnum"
    fi
done

kill "$COPROC_PID"
```

Comment: But then, you don't know what it matches nor in what context those numbers  may be used for. Does it match on `1,23` on locales where `,` is the radix? Does it match on nan, inf, 0x12, `" 123 \t "`?

Comment: My version of `perl` (5.22.1) says that "- " (minus space) is a number.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Ah, well. It was too fun to write for me to delete it. I'll put a disclaimer on top. Hopefully someone will find its use of `coproc` interesting.

Comment: It would be nice to know exactly what it matches on actually. Not easy to tell from the source. For instance, it matches on "0 but true" as well. Can we make it honour the locale's decimal radix?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas It doesn't seem to do normal Perl parsing of numbers: hexadecimals and numbers containing `_` are "not numbers". Tabs and spaces seems to be allowed, but I'm mystified by `-` being a number while `+` is not. The locale does not seem to play in.

Comment: Locale plays if you use `use locale` (or `-Mlocale`). I've just raised a bug about "- " ("\s*-\s+")

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Then locales on my system are broken. I tried `2,2` with `LC_ALL=sv_SE.UTF-8` and got "not a number".  The space may be dropped from the minus btw, and it's still a number.

Comment: `LC_ALL=sv_SE.UTF-8 perl -Mlocale -MScalar::Util -e 'print 0+Scalar::Util::looks_like_number($_) for "1,2", "1.2", "-", "- "'` prints `1101` for me.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas `0101` here. Perl v5.24.2 on OpenBSD 6.2. But with my shell script it says `-` (no space) is a number. Strange.

Comment: https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=132278

Comment: In your script, you're testing "-\n" (so it's another "\s*-\s+"). Add the "-l" option to strip the "\n"

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Ah. Good catch! Thanks. And I saw your bug report already. Let's see what comes out of it. This comment section is too long now. I suggest we let it rest for the time being. I might pick out one or two things and put in my answer. Thanks.

Comment: `Regexp::Common` may be a better alternative here (`perl -MRegexp::Common=number -lne 'print if /^$RE{num}{real}$/'`)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks!  When I have time...