# Make awk produce error on non-numeric

Tags: awk, numeric-data

I have a program that sums a column in a file:

```
awk -v col=2 '{sum+=$col}END{print sum}' input-file
```

However, it has a problem: If you give it a file that doesn't have numeric data, (or if one number is missing) it will interpret it as zero.

I want it to produce an error if one of the fields cannot be parsed as a number.

Here's an example input:

```
bob 1
dave 2
alice 3.5
foo bar
```

I want it to produce an error because 'bar' is not a number, rather than ignoring the error.

Comment: If not a dupe, at least strongly related: [Can I determine type of an awk variable?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/281271)

Comment: by "produce an error", do you mean stop altogether, or skip the line, and/or emit a message?

Comment: Stop altogether and emit a message.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks, that was really helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up with this:

```
awk -v col=$col '
typeof($col) != "strnum" {
    print "Error on line " NR ": " $col " is not numeric"
    noprint=1
    exit 1
}
{
    sum+=$col
}
END {
    if(!noprint)
        print sum
}' $file
```

This uses typeof, which is a GNU awk extension. `typeof($col)` returns 'strnum' if `$col` is a valid number, and 'string' or 'unassigned' if it is not.

See  [Can I determine type of an awk variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281271/can-i-determine-type-of-an-awk-variable)

Answer (score 8):

A reasonable way to test would be to compare the field using tests similar to [`strtod`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtod.html), which is the [method that awk uses](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) to convert strings to numbers:

```
$2 !~ / *[+-]?[[:digit:]]/ { print "NAN: " $2; exit 1; }
```

The above differs from strtod in that it does not consider INFINITY or NAN to be "numbers". The leading space requirement could be relaxed under awk's default field-splitting behavior -- meaning the fields would never contain leading space:

```
$2 !~ /[+-]?[[:digit:]]/ { print "NAN: " $2; exit 1; }
```

A further refinement, thanks to Stéphane's comment and [answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/397788/117549):

```
$2 !~ /^[+-]?([[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*([eE][-+]?[[:digit:]]+)?|0[xX][[:xdigit:]]*\.?[[:xdigit:]]*([pP][-+]?[[:digit:]]+)?)$/ { print "NAN: " $2; exit 1; }
```

Broken out for slightly better legibility, that regex is:

```
/^[+-]?([[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*([eE][-+]?[[:digit:]]+)?|\
        0[xX][[:xdigit:]]*\.?[[:xdigit:]]*([pP][-+]?[[:digit:]]+)?)$/
```

... where the intention is to allow a possible leading + or -, then either a floating point number or hexadecimal number. The floating point number has optional leading digits, an option separator (here fixed to be a period `.`), followed by some number of digits, optionally followed by an exponent. The hex number must start with `0x` or `0X`, followed by hex digits, a separator, more hex digits, and optionally followed by a "power" (exponent). The entire second field must match one of those formats (as anchored by `^` and `$`). Omitted here, for the purposes of this question, are the NAN and INFINITY options.

Another option would be to force a numeric conversion, then compare it to zero and then further compare the original input to something that would convert to zero; more specifically, does it start with an optional + or -, then is it followed by zeros, or followed by a period and zeros:

```
{ number=0 + $2;
  if (!number && $2 !~ /^[+-]?(0+)|\.0+/)
    print "NAN: "$2;
}
```

Comment: You'd need to anchor the regexp (with `^`), otherwise, it's just a test whether the second field contains a decimal digit. You'd also need to take care of numbers like `.123`. There's also whether you want to honour user's decimal radix (comma vs period). The last one would let strings like `.`, `+`, `+.`

Comment: Great points, Stéphane; thank you. I will correct the simpler aspects shortly.

Comment: notice that when converting strings to numbers awk will ignore any trailing junk (see my answer) and `/^[+-]?0*\.?0*$/` is far from being a thorough pattern matching strings that will be *completely* parsed to `0` by `strtod` (what about `0e13`, `.0e-0`, `0x0`, `0x.0p+13`, etc?)

Comment: Point well taken, @UncleBilly, as also noted by Stéphane above. I'm working on the "zero" regex right now...

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -v col=2 '
    $col+0==0 && $col!~/^[+-]?0/ { print "bad number " $col > "/dev/stderr" } 
    {sum+=$col}
    END{print sum}' input-file
```

It's up to you to complicate it if you want it to also handle `.0` or `.0e+33` as valid representations of `0`; notice that `awk` will ignore trailing junk when converting strings to numbers (`"1.4e1e3"+0`, `"1.4e1.e7"+0` or `"14+13"+0` will be all equal to 14).

Answer (score 2):

> If you give it a file that doesn't have numeric data,

```
$col ~ /[^-.[:digit:]]/ {print "Error, non-numeric :"; print $col; exit 1};
```

Explanation just use a RegEx to check for the presence of characters which are not digits nor floating point, sign, etc.

> (or if one number is missing)

add

```
|| ($col == "")
```

or

```
|| (length($col) == 0)
```

to the rule.

Or you could use a comparison to `NF` if it's the last column like in your example.

Answer (score 0):

A little trick I use is trying to get the square root from the string. `awk` will do its utmost to make it right so if trailing 0 is not a number this method is not for you.

```c
if ( sqrt(_varname) ) {
 print "this " _varname " is a (positive) number"
} else {
 print "this " _varname " is not a number..."
}
```